# Getting "Permission Denied" error, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: excel, vba, permissions

I am trying to find a specific file based on the date in it's name in a folder with a bunch of files and move it to another folder, sounds simple right? Well, I am getting

> Permission Denied

error, and I am not sure if my code is bad or if it's a file access issue. Any help would be appreciated! This is my code:

```
Sub MoveFiles()
Dim myValn As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim myDate3 As String
Dim Wmsn As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UPLOADER")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("VARIABLES")

myName = ws2.Range("B2").Value
myValn = ws2.Range("B1").Value
myDate3 = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy")
Wmsn = "WMS_36196_PROD_" & myDate3 & ".csv" 'trying to find the file to move with the current date in it's name
                                            'example filename is WMS_36196_PROD_12-21-2017.csv


'source path below
FileCopy "\\Rdcicgtcuwd01p\app_log\36196_WMS\" & Wmsn, _
"\\olscmesf003\gcm_emea\TCU_REPORTS\APPS\Reports\Regional\Workflow Management System\2017\" 'destination path

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you manually save a file in the target directory?  Is the error returned by the line starting `FileCopy...`.

Comment: I can manually copy/paste the file, that's the process I am trying to automate. That's why I don't understand.Yes the Debug function lands me on the `FileCopy...` line.

Comment: The destination argument must include the file name, a directory on its own is not sufficient & will fail.

Comment: Are you trying to copy a csv that is open in Excel?  You can't do that because Excel locks the file.  You would need to close, copy and then reopen.

Comment: @Alex K so this would be correct?  `"\\Rdcicgtcuwd01p\app_log\36196_WMS\" & Wmsn, _
"\\olscmesf003\gcm_emea\TCU_REPORTS\APPS\Reports\Regional\Workflow Management System\2017\" & Wmsn`

Comment: Yep thats correct.

Comment: @destination-data nope the .csv file isn't open, the vba doesn't interact with it in any way other than copying it, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Yup your suggestion worked like a charm @Alex K, do you want to post it as an answer so that I can mark it or should I just answer the question myself based on your suggestion?

Comment: go ahead and add your answer

Comment: done, thank you so much for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the code based on @Alex K's helpful suggestion and it works perfectly now. The issue was, that I did not specify a filename for the destination, only for the origin. Thanks for the fix!

The correct code is this:

```
Sub WMS()
Dim myValn As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim myDate3 As String
Dim Wmsn As String
Dim Wmsn2 As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UPLOADER")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("VARIABLES")

myName = ws2.Range("B2").Value
myValn = ws2.Range("B1").Value
myDate3 = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy")
Wmsn = "WMS_36196_PROD_" & myDate3 & ".csv"
Wmsn2 = "36196_WMS_" & myDate3 & ".csv"

'source path below
FileCopy "\\Rdcicgtcuwd01p\app_log\36196_WMS\" & Wmsn, "\\olscmesf003\gcm_emea\TCU_REPORTS\APPS\Reports\Regional\Workflow Management System\2017\" & myValn & "\" & Wmsn2

End Sub
```